# std::shared_ptr for concrete Python classes deriving from C++ abstract class using boost::python

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, boost-python

Significant functionality in a C++ library I'm working on relies on `std::shared_ptr`. For example, to add a *Component* to an *Actor* I would call a function with prototype

```
Actor::add_component(std::shared_ptr<Component> cmp);
```

which stores the `std::shared_ptr<Component>` in an internal map. At the C++ level, the application works great.

In trying to create Python bindings relying on `boost::python`, I've run into the problem of creating custom components in Python as classes deriving from the C++ `Component` abstract base class.

This is a minimal but complete example:

```
// C++ library and Python bindings
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <memory>

class Base {
 public:
  virtual ~Base() = default;
  void behavior() const {
    return this->custom_behavior();
  }
 private:
  virtual void custom_behavior() const = 0;
};

class BaseWrapper
    : public Base,
      public boost::python::wrapper<Base> {
 private:
  void custom_behavior() const override {
    this->get_override("custom_behavior")();
  }
};

void foo(const Base& item) {
  item.behavior();
}

void bar(const Base* const item) {
  item->behavior();
}

void baz(const std::shared_ptr<Base>& item) {
  item->behavior();
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(library) {
  using namespace boost::python;

  class_<BaseWrapper,
         std::shared_ptr<BaseWrapper>,
         boost::noncopyable>("Base")
      .def("behavior", &BaseWrapper::behavior)
      ;

  def("foo", &foo);
  def("bar", &bar);
  def("baz", &baz);
}
```

I would expect to create custom components as presented below:

```
import library

class Derived(library.Base):
    def custom_behavior(self):
        print "Derived::custom_behavior()"


def main():

    # Instance of a Python class derived from a C++ class.
    derived = Derived()

    print "direct call to Derived.behavior..."
    derived.behavior()

    print "call foo(const Base& item)"
    library.foo(derived)

    print "call bar(const Base* const item)"
    library.bar(derived)

    print "call baz(const std::shared_ptr<Base>& item)"
    library.baz(derived)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

But, as expected, the call to `baz` fails:

```
$ python test-library.py
direct call to Derived.behavior...
Derived::custom_behavior()
call foo(const Base& item)
Derived::custom_behavior()
call bar(const Base* const item)
Derived::custom_behavior()
call baz(const std::shared_ptr<Base>& item)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test-library.py", line 27, in <module>
    main()
  File "test-library.py", line 23, in main
    library.baz(derived)
Boost.Python.ArgumentError: Python argument types in
    library.baz(Derived)
did not match C++ signature:
    baz(std::shared_ptr<Base>)
```

I've tried to override the constructor of all Python classes deriving from `library.Base`, expecting to "start existing" as `std::shared_ptr<BaseWrapper>`:

```
std::shared_ptr<BaseWrapper> constructor() {
    return std::make_shared<BaseWrapper>();
}

class_<BaseWrapper, std::shared_ptr<BaseWrapper>, noncopyable>
    ("Base", no_init")
    .def("__init__", make_constructor(constructor))
    // ... other methods
    ;
```

but that did not work out --- **any suggestions**?